# How to assign functions to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am coding a Gameboy Emulator, and for the CPU's instructions I use this struct here (in cpp.hpp) to store info about them. The map is used to access all this information  through a key equal to its personal opcode:

```cpp
    struct instruction {
        std::string name;    //name of the instruction
        int cycles;          //clock cycles required to be executed
        int paramNum;        //number of params accepted
        void* function;      //code to be executed
    };
    class Cpu {
        private:
            std::map<unsigned char, instruction> instrMap;
            void Cpu::fillInstructions(void);
            instruction addInstruction(std::string, int, int, void*);
        public:
            void add_A_n(unsigned char);
    }
```

Then in the cpu.cpp I have for example one of the function I want to cast to a function pointer in order to be assigned to the field of the struct instruction. So I have this code:

```cpp
    void Cpu::add_A_n(unsigned char n) {
        //body     
    }
    void Cpu::addInstructions(std::string name, int cycles, int paramNum, void* function) {
        instruction i = {name, cycles, paramNum, function};
        return i;
    }
    void Cpu::fillInstructions() {
        instrMap[0x80] = Cpu::addInstruction("ADD A, n", 4, 0, (void*)&Cpu::add_A_n);
    }
```

The goal is to fetch the opcode from the memory, then to use this opcode to retrieve from the map the information about the relative instruction, and finally to execute its function by using a switch case to select the right one:

```cpp
    ((void (*)(void))instrMap[0x80].function)(); //for 0 params
    ((void (*)(unsigned char))instrMap[0x90].function)((unsigned char)operand); //for 1 param
```

My goal is to cast the all the functions, even the ones who requires some parameters, to the one in the struct.

The respective function it is correctly executed, but a warning is raised:

**warning: converting from 'void (Cpu::*)()' to 'void*' [-Wpmf-conversions]
     instrMap[0x80] = Cpu::addInstruction("ADD A, n", 4, 0, (void*)&Cpu::add_A_n);**

How can I solve it and why does it occur? Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to implement a CPU emulator because you lose type-safety by passing function pointers as `void*`. Have you thought about using a struct to store params passed to a `virtual` function in a subclass that represents the instruction instead?

Comment: Unsolicited advice: Use `std::unordered_map` unless you need ordering in your map, which you probably don't. (There's also a flat map pending in the standard and Google's [flat_hash_map](https://abseil.io/blog/20180927-swisstables) for the time being.)

Comment: @metal It does require C++11, but I will probably need to use it.

Comment: You can also get C++98-compatible hash map from `boost::unordered_map` from which the std version was derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&Cpu::add_A_n` returns a [*pointer to a member function*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members), which is very different from an ordinary function pointer, and the two can't be mixed. The weirdness around pointer to member functions is to account for the fact that non-static member functions all require a `this` instance in order to call the function.

In your case, if a function like `add_A_n` really doesn't depend on `this`, just make it `static`, or a non-member function:

```
class Cpu {
    ...
    static add_A_n(unsigned char);
};
```

This way, it no longer needs a `this` to be called, and `&Cpu::add_A_n` becomes an ordinary function pointer.